# Java BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

I set an initial capacity of the BQ as 3. But some time producer is going beyond the initial capacity. Plz refer output.

**Question Update:** ArrayBlockingQueue uses explicit lock for thread safety but in the code i acquire the monitor/implicit lock of sharedResource object.

How to make `System.out.println("Produce : "+d);` as part of the same explicit lock? /How to achieve the desired output of printing what goes inside the BQ with the same BQ lock?

**Declaration**

```
BlockingQueue<String> sharedResource = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(3);
```

**Producer**

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            try {

                String d = Thread.currentThread().getName() + "->" + i;
                synchronized (sharedResource) {
                    sharedResource.put(d);
                    System.out.println("Produce : " + d);
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Consumer**

```
Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            try {
                System.out.println("C : " + sharedResource.take());
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**OutPut**

```
***P1->1
P3->1
P5->1
P2->1***
C : P1->1
C : P3->1
P4->1
C : P5->1
P2->2
P5->2
C : P2->1
P3->2
C : P4->1
P1->2
C : P2->2
P4->2
C : P5->2
C : P3->2
C : P1->2
C : P4->2
```

**Update**: I call the producer and consumer as below.

```
Thread producer1 = new Thread(r);
Thread producer2 = new Thread(r);
Thread producer3 = new Thread(r);
Thread producer4 = new Thread(r);
Thread producer5 = new Thread(r);

producer1.setName("P1");
producer2.setName("P2");
producer3.setName("P3");
producer4.setName("P4");
producer5.setName("P5");

producer1.start();
producer2.start();
producer3.start();
producer4.start();
producer5.start();

consumer.start();
```

Comment: Please show your code on how producer is called. It seems you started multiple producer threads, and the number of producer threads(P1, P2, ...) does nothing with the capacity of the BQ

Comment: ArrayBlockingQueue uses explicit lock for thread safety but in the code i acquire the monitor/implicit lock of sharedResource object.

Comment: How to make System.out.println("Produce : "+d); as part of the same explicit lock?

Comment: Firstly, `synchronized` is not necessary because `BlockingQueue` is thread-safe by design.

Comment: And it is difficult to catch your question, do you mean "the 4th output `P2->1` is strange because we already have P1->1, P3->1, P5->1 before it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is exactly that "the 4th output P2->1 is strange" as I described in comments.

Here is my answer:

**The BQ works well but this is the problem of the synchronization with BQ operation and System.out**

If you want your output correct, the following block

```
sharedResource.put(d);
System.out.println("Produce : " + d);
```

should be a **atomic operation**, either to

```
System.out.println("C : " + sharedResource.take());
```

But since `put` and `take` already block the thread, it is not easy to merge the `System.out` into the lock of `put` and `take`.

I do not know what is your purpose to print the messages. If just for testing whether Java BQ works well, I promise you "yes".

If you really want your correct output, I recommend you to implement your own BQ and make `System.out` inside the lock.

Comment: Yes. My Question is about the 4th Output. I am printing just for testing purpose.

Comment: Btw, what is the performance difference between ArrayBlockingQueue and LinkedBlockingQueue?

Comment: This is quite another question, though, you can use Google to get a lot. Here is [one](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/java-best-practices-queue-battle-and.html)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty simple in ArrayBlockingQueue#take() method

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29)

It says when you call take it "Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available." 
So it reduces the queue size by 1 so 
consider 
1. you have 4 elements in queue 
2. you call take() 
3. the queue size will reduce to 3

hence you queue does not exceed the size **3** in your case.
You are putting as well as removing values from the queue at the same time so queue size does not exceed 3
However if you slowdown your consumer by Thread.sleep(500); you will get the desired output.